# Read paramlist Oracle Forms 10gR2

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

is it possible to read all paramlist in Oracle Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `GET_PARAMETER_LIST(name)` to retrieve a parameter list in Forms. However, you must know what the name of the parameter list is. To find out, look at the code that is calling the form that sets the parameter list - e.g. look for code that calls `CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST`.

Generally I prefer to use a single standard name for all parameter lists, to avoid confusion.

Comment: No, I want to get all paramlist in string, is it posible?

Comment: No, it is not possible using the features provided by Oracle Forms.